# How to show the marker quantity in cluster

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am trying to do something like this https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/clustering/marker-clustering

I need to change the icon but keep the number that represents the quantity of markers in a cluster.

I was able to change the icon but I could not keep the quantity.

Answer (score 1):

I just could do it this way:

Having a SVG with

```
 <text id="!" font-family="Montserrat-SemiBold, Montserrat" font-size="13" font-weight="500" fill="#ECECEC">
                        <tspan x="3.193" y="15">{text}!</tspan>
                    </text>
```

And then on a custom theme:

```
CustomTheme = {
                getClusterPresentation: cluster => {
                    const weight = cluster.getWeight();
                    const radius = weight * 5;

                    const svgString = icons.alertClusterPresentation
                        .replace(/\{text\}/g, weight.toString());
                    const clusterMarker = new H.map.Marker(cluster.getPosition(), {
                        icon: new H.map.Icon(svgString, {
                            size: { w: radius, h: radius },
                            crossOrigin: false,
                        }),
                        // Set min/max zoom with values from the cluster,
                        // otherwise clusters will be shown at all zoom levels:
                        min: cluster.getMinZoom(),
                        max: cluster.getMaxZoom(),
                    });
                    return clusterMarker;
                },
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of libraries available in market based on Quadtree Algorithm.

Refer this:-

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer